# How can I detect if two file entries refer to the same physical file system with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, filesystems

I have a link to the file and an actual file. How can I detect if both of them refer to the same physical location?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

bool isSameFileSystem(QString path1, QString path2)
{
   struct stat stat1, stat2;
   QFileInfo fi1(path1);
   QFileInfo  fi2(path2);
   stat(fi1.absoluteDir().absolutePath().toUtf8().constData(), &stat1);
   stat(fi2.absoluteDir().absolutePath().toUtf8().constData(), &stat2);
   return stat1.st_dev == stat2.st_dev;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to detect whether or not the given file spec is a symbolic link spec or a real file system object:

```
bool point2Same(QString path1, QString path2)
{
    QFileInfo fi1(path1);
    QFileInfo fi2(path2);

    QString p1, p2;
    if (fi1.isSymLink())
        p1 = fi1.symLinkTarget();
    else
        p1 = fi1.absolutePath();

    if (fi2.isSymLink())
        p2 = fi2.symLinkTarget();
    else
        p2 = fi2.absolutePath();

    return p1 == p2;
}
```

Comment: Duplicated code could be moved to a separate function, though.

Comment: I don't think this is a reliable solution. In documentation for `isSymLink` real symbolic NTFS links are not explicitly mentioned. And even if symbolic NTFS links are handled what about hard links or junctions (mounted directories)?

Comment: Well, according to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#isSymLink it reads .lnk files on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

You can either scan a QFileSystemModel, or perhaps subclass it? It's a quick way to pull in a file system from a specified root and have access to the tree & its properties.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure what QFileSystemModel is for?

Comment: Lol im reading the question and wondering what i was thinking now.